# Does mysql index modify on update?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Let's say i have a mysql database table 'article' with the following fields: `id`, `title`, `url`, `views`

I have the field `title` marked with a `FULLTEXT` index and the field `url` marked with a `UNIQUE` index.

My question is, if i do an ordinary update something like:

```
UPDATE 'article' SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = {id}
```

...will this result in a update of the mysql table indexes?

Is it safe (from speed point of view) to keep the field `views` in the table `article` or maybe i should create a separate table, let's say, `article_stats` with the following fields: `article_id`, `views` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `UPDATE` statements update indexes. MySQL manages indexes automatically - you never need to worry about updating them manually or triggering an update. If you are asking whether that particular `UPDATE` will change your indexes which don't include the `views` column - no, it wont. Only related indexes get updated.

Keeping a `views` column is fine, unless you need to track extra information about each view (when it occurred, user who made the view, etc)

Your SQL does contain a syntax error, however. You can't quote table names like `'article'`. If you need to quote a table name (e.g. if it contains a SQL reserved word), then use backticks like this:

```
UPDATE  `article` SET ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cal, index gets updated with update statement "if you update the index". In your case specific example the index or indexes are not updated because they are not related to the view field but updating the view will still slow down because that's such a frequent operation and you can programmatically keep the view updates in a shared memory with a binary tree or hash table and update them together after some time or size point. For the best speed you also can use memory tables, which are volatile but you can transfer the data from time to time to the actual table. By this way you won't get to deal with harddisk writer for every "view" update.

Keeping seperate table will result the same thing. Your application slows down because there is an update when there is a select - that row you are updating will be locked until you done with it and another readers will wait your row-level operation. You will still have selects to show that view count even in a seperate table.

Well, when you have that much load, you can have master and slave servers to seperate reads and writes and synchronize time to time.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that indexes are refreshed on mysql update, but i wasn't sure if the refresh take place even if i don't update an indexed field. So Cal said, for my particular example, that indexes are not updated. Are you saying otherwise? I'm sorry to ask again but i just want to be very sure.

Comment: Also related to your second statement, more precisely "Your application slows down because there is an update when there is a select." ... are you referring to the fact the mysql query looks like this: UPDATE article SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = {id} ? Is it faster to have a query like UPDATE article SET views = {number} WHERE id = {id} for example?

Comment: @Gabriel I updated the answer, I hope it is more clear. The "view" count is such a common bottleneck to update because it is always frequent. I wasn't referrering to that query when I said "Your application slows down because there is an update when there is a select.". I simply say your selection queries wait if the row is locked by an update, in a row level, and that is the reason of "slowing down". So to prevent this as I suggest you can have a seperate "buffer" in memory to keep modifications to table and do it at once.